# RESTFul Android ContentProvider URI

Tags: android, rest, uri, android-contentprovider, one-to-many

To be RESTful, the URI to get the comments for a post, should be something like:

```
posts/#/comments
```

Where `#` is the post id that will change depending on which post your are interested in.

I want to apply some convention when designing the content URI of my content provider. The question is, how  is the user of the content provider expected to construct such a URI in an elegant way?

A workable solution is :

```
//in PostProvider
public static URI CONTENTS_URI_POSTS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/posts");
public static String COMMENTS = "comments";
```

Then the user will use `Uri.builder` to combine  `CONTENTS_URI_POSTS` + `id` + `COMMENTS`. However, this method exposes the details on how to construct a URI.

To hide the details, maybe I could add a method:

```
 public static URI  buildContentUriToGetPostComments(int post_id);
```

Any better idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a model for Comment and Post? Maybe they could provide a method to build a URI...

Comment: @pierr Can you please update you question or supply an answer yourself, if you found a solution to your problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use different paths for posts and their comments:

```
content://<authority>/posts/#<post-id>
content://<authority>/comments/#<post-id>
```

This way you have an URI which looks more conventional and its simpler to handle in the content provider, you do not need to parse the URI but a standard UriMatcher will do.

Comment: Actually, I like your idea. But I cannot imagine how this would work in the scenario that pierr described. There is a `has_many` relationship between `posts` and `comments`. Therefore, only the content URI of the post will be available when starting a request for comments that targets the content provider. Could you please add more details to your answer?

Comment: Yes, there is one-to-many releationship between posts and comments. But you do not need to make this explicit in the URI, only the database (or whatever implements persistence here) needs to know that. If you access comments via the 2nd URI using the post-id, the content provider uses the knowledge of the releationship between posts and comments to access the comments for the given post.

Answer (score 1):

Not to bring up something old, but I am having trouble implementing this one-to-many relationship as well... If I follow Stefans approach:

```
content://<authority>/comments/#<post-id>
```

What if I later want to add a URI to get a specific comment by id?

```
content://<authority>/comments/#<comment-id>
```

The above would create an identical match to the previous URI.

In my case, I tried to resolve this by using

```
content://<authority>/posts/comments/#<post-id>
```

However, this solution can cause problems. For example, if I want to load a cursor using both:

```
content://<authority>/comments/  (all comments)
content://<authority>/posts/comments/#<post-id> (comments by post)
```

and insert a comment using:

```
content://<authority>/comments
```

Not all users of the ContentProvider will be notified, as the URI pattern doesn't match.

To solve this, I make sure that my ContentProvider calls notifyChange with the appended ID to BOTH of the 'get all' URI AND the 'get by post id' URI... this is just one solution.

Any drawbacks to implementing it this way? In hindsight it would probably be easier to just rely on the user setting the foreign key in the selection string of the ContentProvider query... but like pierr I wanted to implement it as a single URI.